# Where do I get data to train a program?

Tags: machine-learning

I am creating a learning program which should learn how to answer to a binary yes/no question given numeric information.

For now, I used [this data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29) to train it:

The problem is, I only have 569 records. It is not few, but I'd like more. Also, I should train it with other types of data (not related to breast cancer), to see how it does with different classes of problems.

What I need is a list of records each containing a bunch of numeric fields and a yes/no answer (such as "Is this tumor malicious?" in the data I already use).

Does anybody know where to find such repositories?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with breast cancer -
http://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2008/Data

For every year (1997-2014) there is a data set. Just change the year in URL

```
http://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-xxxx/Data
```

You can also check http://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/experiments. If you sign up for Azure ML (it is free) you can download any data set used in any of these experiments.

Comment: Thank you so much. The reason I took long to anser is that I don't really know how to read that data, so I couldn't at first understand if it's what I am looking for. Each record contains a list of 117 records, but from the page you linked I could not understand how to associate to each record its answer (malignant or benign). Can you understand that data better than I do?

Comment: [Here](http://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/685a8552833a4082acec1d5a017efa70) is described how to use data sets. It also includes step by step tutorial for Azure ML